# Paypal: Handling disputes, which API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

After getting any type of IPN into my system fine, my issue now is how to handle disputes/claims/etc without logging into paypal store each time.

How can I post messages or escalate the claim from my own system?

I've done some googling and found there are these API calls:

```
CheckIsDisputeAllowed, CloseDispute,OpenDispute, UpdateDisputeItems, PostDisputeMessage, OpenExternalDispute, CloseExternalDispute
```

and subsequently have found these maybe in the **payflow pro api**.  However, I am using the web payments pro system.

Has anyone else done this?

Essentially handling all claims/disputes from their own system rather than logging into paypal each time?

Oh and currently I am using the sandbox, so if you know whether or not these work let me know.  So I can save myself some frustration.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know these are limited API's, not generally available to all merchants. They would need to be posted to the PayPal API endpoint, though.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal only give merchants with a high volume of monthly transaction access to the dispute APIs. The threshold doesn't seem to be fixed, I've heard different figures from the PayPal business support team in the UK. But as a rule of thumb, if you're turning over in excess of a $1m annually give them a call and put in a request for access.